# Punctuation correction with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to make a regex that will fix various grammatical errors with punctuation. There's only a few simple requirements:

- A punctuation mark should follow imitatively after a word (no space)
- There should always be a space after a punctuation mark
- Repeated punctuation marks should have no space between them

So far I got this:

```
(?:\s*)([?!.,]+)(?:\s*)
```

Substituted with \1. This fixes point 1 and 2, but it adds spaces between punctuation as well.

I tried running another regex just to fix point 3:

```
[!?.,]( )[!?,.]
```

but this also removes the punctuation marks themselves even though they are not part of any capture group?

**Example behavior**:

Input: "what! is .this this,gdjs gf fg fddsf . . ."

Desired output: "what! is. this this, gdjs gf fg fddsf..."

Comment: What regex flavor and add some examples

Comment: By **word** you mean an alphanumeric character ? or something else ?

Comment: Point 2 and 3 are contradictory. How can there be repeated punctuation marks without space (point 3) if there should be a space after each one(point2) ?

Comment: @noob Word is [a-zA-Z].

Comment: Point 2 and 3 are contradictory if taken literately, which is why i have the problem that I am having, but to clear up: There should only be a space if he next character is not a punctuation mark.

Comment: Could you post any sample string to test against?

Comment: BTW, [Point 3 is OK with your regex](https://regex101.com/r/bS9bT9/1)

Comment: @Limonup: Since you didn't mentioned **flavour** I devised a regex, which will work with perl, php and python but not in `javascript` because of `lookbehind` assertion is not supported in it.

Comment: "what! is .this this,gdjs gf fg fddsf . . ."
Should become:
"what! is. this this, gdjs gf fg fddsf..."

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried it in python and it doesnt work: https://ideone.com/6xFBWO

Comment: Note that in string "what! is .this this,gdjs gf fg fddsf . . ." , just after last `f` there is a space and then punctuation. But you mentioned that it should follow after a word.

Comment: What about [this demo](https://ideone.com/hGXsx7)?

Comment: As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool. Note that Python re module is not that powerful as .NET, Boost or PCRE/PCRE2 regex flavor, so, lots of stuff should be done via code.

Comment: @noob Yes, the first string is demo example, so in the desired output you see that I have no space after the final f

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that is perfect. Also I didn't know they were different. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match multiple punctuation symbols together with whitespace and then remove the whitespace inbetween punctuation symbols within a lambda:

```
import re

fix_spaces = re.compile(r'\s*([?!.,]+(?:\s+[?!.,]+)*)\s*')
text = "what! is .this this,gdjs gf fg fddsf . . ."
text = fix_spaces.sub(lambda x: "{} ".format(x.group(1).replace(" ", "")), text)
print(text.strip())
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/hGXsx7).

You may use a regex inside the lambda to remove whitespace, too:

```
re.sub(r"\s+", "", x.group(1))
```

The regex matches:

- `\s*` - leading whitespace (zero or more)
- `([?!.,]+(?:\s+[?!.,]+)*)` - Group 1 matching one or more characters from `[?!.,]` set, followed with zero or more groups of one or more whitespacees followed with one or more punctuation from the `[?!.,]` set
- `\s*` - zero or more trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided which lacked any specific flavor I came up with following solution.

**Regex**: `/(?<=[A-Za-z])[?!.,]+(?= )/g`

**Explanation**:

1) `[?!.,]+(?= )` matches one or more punctuation followed by a space.

2) `(?<=[A-Za-z])` the matched punctuation should be preceded by at least one letter.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lI3vU2/1)**</kbd>